# what is the minimum no of DFA states required to recognise below language?

Tags: automata

$L=\{a^nk , k>0 \text{ and } n \text{ is an integer constant} \}$

In this question which constant should be changed , n or k while considering the DFA since then it can be either $n+1$ or $k+1$ ?

Comment: You mean, perhaps $a^{nk}$? Anyway, $k$ is the better choice of letter for an integer $constant$...* **c**onstant* begins with that sound, $n$ is more commonly the variable. The problem says that one is a constant, the other isn't, so what could you possibly mean, "which constant"?

Comment: But in the question n is an integer constant ,while nothing is mentioned about K ,since K>0 ,it implies that k must also be a constant only .

Comment: No, no, $k$ can be any integer $> 0$.